# Merging segments from the same trips into a single trip for analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the MWE below, I show my attempt to line-plot trips (from my `df` aggregated per month):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

d = {'user': [62, 62, 154, 154, 154, 73, 73, 73, 73],
     'start': ['2008-06-20 04:21:40','2008-06-20 05:40:31','2007-05-01 10:10:00',
         '2007-05-01 10:36:00','2007-05-01 15:30:00','2008-05-19 16:25:54',
          '2008-05-21 02:21:37','2008-05-22 01:30:09','2008-05-29 01:55:59'],
    'end': ['2008-06-20 05:33:46','2008-06-20 05:53:11', '2007-05-01 10:36:00',
         '2007-05-01 11:00:00','2007-05-01 15:55:00','2008-05-19 16:29:22',
         '2008-05-21 02:25:04','2008-05-22 01:33:51','2008-05-29 01:59:25'],
 'mode': ['bus','walk','bus','walk','taxi','walk','walk','walk','walk'],}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[['start', 'end']] = df[['start', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

df['Date'] = df['start'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

df.sort_values(['Date' ], ascending=True, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# aggregate monthly trips
df = df.groupby(['Date']).size().reset_index().rename(
    columns={0:'Trips'})
df
    Date   Trips
0   2007-05 3
1   2008-05 4
2   2008-06 2

# the I can plot trips like so:
sns.lineplot(data=df, x = df['Date'], y='Trips')
```

I realised in my `df`, some trips contains jump (maybe due to data log), so they should be merged into single trip before aggregation. In the given `df` example above (before grouping).

```
df
   user        start                 end       mode     Date
0   154 2007-05-01 10:10:00 2007-05-01 10:36:00 bus     2007-05
1   154 2007-05-01 10:36:00 2007-05-01 11:00:00 walk    2007-05
2   154 2007-05-01 15:30:00 2007-05-01 15:55:00 taxi    2007-05
3   73  2008-05-19 16:25:54 2008-05-19 16:29:22 walk    2008-05
4   73  2008-05-21 02:21:37 2008-05-21 02:25:04 walk    2008-05
5   73  2008-05-22 01:30:09 2008-05-22 01:33:51 walk    2008-05
6   73  2008-05-29 01:55:59 2008-05-29 01:59:25 walk    2008-05
7   62  2008-06-20 04:21:40 2008-06-20 05:33:46 bus     2008-06
8   62  2008-06-20 05:40:31 2008-06-20 05:53:11 walk    2008-06
```

`User 154` does undertake 2-trips, not 3. First started at `10:10:00` on bus then changes travel mode to at `10:36:00` to `walk`. Also `user 62` does only a trip, started at `04:21:40 - 05:33:46`  on a bus, then stopped, waited for about 6-minutes then continued to at about `05:40:31`.

**Question**

I want to merge such trips into a single trip so that if the time interval between the end of a user's trip to beginning of the next is less than 30 minutes, that should be considered a single trip. Then I can plot,

In the above MWE, the aggregated trips are "over-estimated", the expected final `df` should be:

```
    Date     Trips
0   2007-05     2
1   2008-05     4
2   2008-06     1
```

Comment: Am I having a deja-vu or is your question really really similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605677/pandas-groupby-time-in-series-to-take-into-account-different-dates#comment128254016_72605677)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function:

```
offset = pd.DateOffset(minutes=30)
merge_trip = lambda x: x['start'].ge(x['end'].shift() + offset).cumsum().add(1)

df['Trips'] = df.groupby('user').apply(merge_trip).droplevel('user')

out = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Trips'].max()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      Date  Trips
0  2007-05      2
1  2008-05      4
2  2008-06      1

>>> df
   user               start                 end  mode     Date  Trips
0   154 2007-05-01 10:10:00 2007-05-01 10:36:00   bus  2007-05      1
1   154 2007-05-01 10:36:00 2007-05-01 11:00:00  walk  2007-05      1
2   154 2007-05-01 15:30:00 2007-05-01 15:55:00  taxi  2007-05      2
3    73 2008-05-19 16:25:54 2008-05-19 16:29:22  walk  2008-05      1
4    73 2008-05-21 02:21:37 2008-05-21 02:25:04  walk  2008-05      2
5    73 2008-05-22 01:30:09 2008-05-22 01:33:51  walk  2008-05      3
6    73 2008-05-29 01:55:59 2008-05-29 01:59:25  walk  2008-05      4
7    62 2008-06-20 04:21:40 2008-06-20 05:33:46   bus  2008-06      1
8    62 2008-06-20 05:40:31 2008-06-20 05:53:11  walk  2008-06      1
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use [`piso`](https://piso.readthedocs.io), specifically the [`bridge`](https://piso.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/piso.bridge.html#piso.bridge) method which is used to fill gaps in an interval index which are below a threshold

Define a function which takes a dataframe, creates an interval index, then applies `piso.bridge` and returns a `pandas.Series` of the start times.

```
import pandas as pd
import piso

def bridge(df):
    ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df["start"], df["end"])
    return piso.bridge(ii, pd.Timedelta("30m")).left.to_series()
```

Then group by user and apply this function, convert to monthly periods, and count values

```
df.groupby("user").apply(bridge).dt.to_period("M").value_counts()
```

This gives a Series, indexed by the month periods

```
2008-05    4
2007-05    2
2008-06    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

**note**: I am the creator of piso. Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.